# Select a contact from the list

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I'm writing an application that listens for the specific command, e.g. "send money to", and I want user to choose a contact from the list of available contacts (like in "send message to" command) after "send money to" is selected. Shame on me, but I cannot find any suitable example on how to implement that feature.

Answer (score 0):

You can display a list of items (scrollable) which is displayed only when it' s triggered a word what you have defined.

You should have a look here, this is pretty awesome and really useful : https://github.com/pscholl/glass_snippets/tree/master/esslib

In you case your can define your triggered word as "send money to", which will display your contacts list.

Hope it helps !